# Proper Way to do Calculations in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

```
Baseline Table

ProjectId   ProjectName    Forecast
---------   -----------    --------
  11258      Test Proj1      0.678 
  11259      Test Proj2      2.57 

FundEntity Baseline Table

ProjectId    FundEntityId    Forecast    ForecastDollars
---------    -----------     --------    ---------------
  11258          5             0.226
  11258          8             0.226
  11258          11            0.226
```

I have a stored procedure that loops through each entry in the ProjectSummaryEntity Table (Yuck!) and for each one, break the forecast down based on "allocations" set in the FundEntity table. Then, I need to calculate the dollar amount of the forecast based on a certain rate in a "Rate" table. The rate is determined by the FundEntity as well.

The stored procedure is running a bit slow (14s for 6.6k rows) and I'm not surprised due to inefficiency of code. My question is, how do I do "on the fly" calculations without using cursors?

The reason why I use cursors is that:

- forecast amount is broken down first (from ProjectSummary), saved to a variable
- rate is determined, saved to variable
- dollar amount is determined, saved to a variable
- final update statement is run to update forecast and forecast dollars

If I don't use cursors there's no way to update the dollars based on the forecast. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: The above is a really simplified version of the whole thing. The stored procedure that deals with this is in: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/629888/

Comment: Share the rest of your table structure please.

Comment: Can you give the Cursor based code?  I'm nearly positive you won't need them, but I'd need to see the code to understand why you think you do...

Comment: @Dems I edited my post and included a link to a pastebin since the code is fairly long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Stored Procedure will run slow not because of your cursor, but because of the subqueries you need to run per row (11 selects + 1 update). Just by combining some of those queries you should be able to significantly improve performance (e.g. the calculations for forHcm, budgetHcm and revPlanHcm could easily be joined into one query as they all are calculations on Baseline table columns).

To answer your specific cursor question, it is possible to remove the cursor as you don't need to generate row output values based on output values for other rows (e.g. if the value of hcmRate for one fundEntityBaselineId was calculated using hcmRate values for another FundEntityBaselineId values, then it would be very difficult to avoid the cursor).
The final query without cursor though will be a little complex.

Taking your stored procedure at http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/629888/ and assuming that if you use COALESCE I need an OUTER JOIN (no COALESCE then INNER JOIN), here is what your single query should look like (to fix the sections marked "refactor" I would need to know more about your tables):

```
SELECT fblId,
       ForecastAmount * fundAlloc AS foreHCM
       hcmRate,
       RE_Value * fundAlloc AS reqForeHcm,
       PlanAmount * fundAlloc AS budgetHcm
       RevisedPlanAmount * fundAlloc AS revPlanHcm,
       actualForHcm_pre * fundAlloc AS actualForeCastHcm
FROM
(SELECT b.FundEntityBaselineId AS fblId,
        COALESCE(fa.fundAllocation,100)/100 as fundAlloc,
        COALESCE(hcmRate1.Usd_Rate,hcmRate2.HCMRate) as hcmRate,
        bl.ForecastAmount,
        COALESCE(re.Value,0) as RE_Value,
        planHcmRate.BudgetHcmRate as planHcmRate,
        bl.PlanAmount,
        bl.RevisedPlanAmount,
        COALESCE(afp_p.actualForHcm_pre,0) as actualForHcm_pre
        FROM FundEntityBaseline b
          INNER JOIN ProjectDetail pd ON pd.ProjectId = b.fblProjectId
          INNER JOIN Baseline bl on bl.BaselineId = b.BaselineId
          INNER JOIN ProjectTeam pt ON bl.ProjectTeamId = pt.ProjectTeamId
        INNER JOIN SiteTeam st ON pt.SiteTeamId = st.SiteTeamId
        INNER JOIN TeamRole tr ON st.TeamRoleId = tr.RoleId
        INNER JOIN Team t ON tr.TeamId = t.TeamId
          INNER JOIN FundSource fs on fs.FundSourceId = pd.FundSourceId
          INNER JOIN (<* refactor*> SELECT r.BudgetHcmRate
                           FROM Rate r WHERE r.RateName = (SELECT st.RateName
                                                           FROM SiteTeam st INNER JOIN ProjectTeam pt 
                                                                                ON st.SiteTeamId = pt.SiteTeamId
                                                                            INNER JOIN Baseline bl 
                                                                                ON bl.ProjectTeamId = pt.ProjectTeamId
                                                           WHERE bl.BaselineId = fblBaselineId
                                                           FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)
                           ORDER BY r.EffectiveDate
                           FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) as planHcmRate,
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT er.Usd_Rate
                            FROM FundEntity fe
                                INNER JOIN EntityCustomerRate er
                                    ON fe.FundAux1 = er.EntityCustomerRateId) AS hcmRate1 
                                    ON hcmRate1.FundEntityId = b.FundEntityId AND (fs.FundingType IN ('Direct Bill-Single','Direct Bill-Multiple')) AND t.teamType = 'ITDEVMO'
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (<* refactor*> SELECT r.HCMRate
                             FROM Rate r
                                INNER JOIN SiteTeam st ON r.RateName = st.RateName
                                INNER JOIN ProjectTeam pt ON st.SiteTeamId = pt.SiteTeamId
                             WHERE pt.ProjectTeamId = (SELECT bl.ProjectTeamId
                                                       FROM Baseline bl
                                                       WHERE bl.BaselineId = b.BaselineId)
                             ORDER BY r.EffectiveDate DESC
                             FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) as hcmRate2 ON (fs.FundingType NOT IN ('Direct Bill-Single','Direct Bill-Multiple') OR t.teamType != 'ITDEVMO')
          LEFT OUTER JOIN FundAllocation fa on fa.FundSourceId = pd.FundSourceId AND fa.FundEntityId = b.fblFundEntity
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Request re on bl.ProjectMonth = re.ProjectMonth AND bl.ProjectTeamId = re.ProjectTeamId AND re.BaselineType = 'Reforecast'
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (<*refactor *>SELECT (((SELECT SUM(bl.ForecastAmount) 
                              FROM Baseline bl 
                              WHERE DATE(SUBSTR(bl.ProjectMonth, 5) || '-' || 
                                        (CASE SUBSTR(bl.ProjectMonth, 1, 3)
                                             WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
                                             WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
                                             WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
                                             WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
                                             WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
                                             WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
                                             WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
                                             WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
                                             WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
                                             WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
                                             WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
                                             WHEN 'Dec' THEN '12'
                                         END) || '-01') > DATE((SELECT CurrentMonth FROM Pmo)) AND
                                    bl.ProjectTeamId = (SELECT ProjectTeamId FROM Baseline WHERE BaselineId = fblBaselineId)) 
                              +
                             (SELECT SUM(bl.HcmActualAmount) 
                              FROM Baseline bl 
                              WHERE DATE(SUBSTR(bl.ProjectMonth, 5) || '-' || 
                                        (CASE SUBSTR(bl.ProjectMonth, 1, 3)
                                             WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
                                             WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
                                             WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
                                             WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
                                             WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
                                             WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
                                             WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
                                             WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
                                             WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
                                             WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
                                             WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
                                             WHEN 'Dec' THEN '12'
                                         END) || '-01') <= DATE((SELECT CurrentMonth FROM Pmo)) AND
                                    bl.ProjectTeamId = (SELECT ProjectTeamId FROM Baseline WHERE BaselineId = fblBaselineId))) as actualForeHcm_pre) AS afh_p
        WHERE ProjectId = projId) as T;
```

Let me know if this is helpful or you need more explanation.